# Spring:failed to load applicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, maven

My project has `service` module which has `applicationContext.xml` on `src/main/resources` path.

I run integration test using `maven-cargo` plugin and dependency looks like

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <spring.profiles.active>${spring.profiles.active}</spring.profiles.active>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <dependencies combine.children="append">
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <!--<logLevel>warn</logLevel>-->
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>cargo.datasource.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
                                cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pryme_common;create=true|
                                cargo.datasource.username=sa|</cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>com.org.common</groupId>
                            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>common</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I run my integration test as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class ITCache extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void testCaches() {
        {
            final String url = "http://localhost:9090/common/rest";
            final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            final WebTarget target = client.target(url).path("networks");
            final Invocation.Builder builder = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            final Response response = builder.get();
            assertStatus(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response);
        }
        assertNotNull(applicationContext);
        final SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = (SimpleCacheManager) applicationContext.getBean("cacheManager");
        System.out.println("cacheName:" + simpleCacheManager.getCacheNames().toString());
        System.out.println(simpleCacheManager.getCache("genders").toString());
    }
}
```

and I see error as

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.018 sec <<< FAILURE!
testCaches(com.org.comma.integration.ITCache)  Time elapsed: 0.016 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:235)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
        ... 43 more
```

Although I do see that file

```
$jar -tvf integration/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat7x/webapps/common.war | grep app     
  2342 Wed Jul 16 16:16:10 PDT 2014 WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
```

Comment: try `classpath:/applicationContext.xml`

Comment: can you try dumping classpath at runtime `System.out.println(System.getProperty"java.class.path"));` and see if one of those path has this xml file ?

Comment: no I do not see it in `java.class.path` either, phew! whats the issue?

Comment: can you analyze your `mvn help:effective-pom` if it overrides your `resources`

Comment: I don't know what that means, but here is the output http://pastebin.com/SkZZrXQS

Comment: your file is at `/Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/comma/services/src/main/resources` ? and which goal you ran ?

Comment: `mvn clean install -pl integration`

Answer (score 0):

Change your @ContextConfiguration annotation as below

```
@ContextConfiguration (locations = "classpath*:/applicationContext*.xml")
```

this will allow the JUnit test case to load the file applicationContext.xml from your classpath